# Could load statements from a file by Cassandra Datastax driver?

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax

Is there possibility to load/execute queries from a file using Cassandra Datastax driver? I could not find any class/method to do that.
As I know the driver can create Batch statements, so I need only the mechanism which can load .cql file and create BatchStatement object.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention which language you are using, but assuming it is Java, currently this is not possible.

There is a Java driver [open ticket](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-928) that requests that feature but it is currently not scheduled. A [server-side ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9048) has also been logged but is currently delayed.

Your best option IMHO would be [cassandra-loader](https://github.com/brianmhess/cassandra-loader).

Comment: Yes, it is Java. Thanks for your answer, it is what I expected.